# How to Ignore directory index file in Symbolic links?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symlink, httpd.conf

I made symbolic link : `ln -s / link` to the root ..

The directory contains an index file (index.php , index.html) etc..,

I can`t have a listing of the content , i get the index directly ..

I want to know how to get a listing of the content even if an index file is present.

Answer (score 1):

Index file used by Apache is driven by the **DirectoryIndex** directive. If you alter this directive in your VirtualHost or Directory with a file name that does not exists, you will prevent apache from finding this file.

So for example let's say you want this behavior for the directory /foo

```
<Directory /foo>
   # we need this option activated the get automatic listing
   Option +Indexes
   DirectoryIndex not_a_directory_index.does_not_exists.file
</Directory>
```